# implement Single Sign On using Spring and Active Directory

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have a Spring based Web App which I would like to implement a Single Sign On solution on.

The basic flow would be:

1. User logs in into Windows Workstation/Desktop PC (authenticating against organisation's Active Directory)
2. User opens browser and navigates to Spring Web App.
3. Spring Web App somehow confirms that the user is already authenticated against AD and seamlessly lets them in. i.e. no challenge for username and password. In fact, the Spring web app would NEVER show a login form.

Obviously it's step 3 I am having trouble with.

I have looked at Spring Security, Kerberos, SPNEGO but I think I've just confused myself.

Comment: When a user logging in, create a DB entry with expiration datestamp and login info. On log out delete the DB entry. If the log out missing the expiration date get value. Check this in the login filter to determine wether the web app access is allowed or not.

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable suggestion but i need to implement SSO + Spring security by using AD users

Answer (score 1):

Try yo use a Cas Server: https://apereo.github.io/cas/6.0.x/index.html

Kerberos and SPNEGO authentication are suported.

To add SSO authentication to an Spring web application is enough to add a web filter.

Avois your application of authentication process and delegate to Cas.

Comment: Thank you for ur valuable suggestion , i will try out

Comment: Did this work? Can you please let me know? I am looking for something similar